# Jquery slideshow can't open new page/html link when clicking on images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to open a new .html page whenever someone clicks on cptmorgan.jpg, that's the only image I need to open a new page when clicked however the Jmorph script is already using the a href in the

element. Anybody got an idea?

Code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">

        <div class="jmorph">
            <div class="imageContainer">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="currentImg" style>
                    <div class="nextImg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            <a href="#previous" class="previous">&lt;&nbsp;Prev</a>
            <div class="bandContainer">
            <ul class="band">
                <li><a href="amanda.jpg">amanda</a></li>
                <li><a href="brandi.jpg">brandi</a></li>
                <li><a href="brittany.jpg">brittany</a></li>
                <li><a href="cptmorgan.jpg">captain morgan</a></li>
                <li><a href="janet.jpg">janet</a></li>
                <li><a href="jonathan.jpg">jonathan</a></li>
                <li><a href="kro-j.jpg">kro-j</a></li>
                <li><a href="lindsay.jpg">lindsay</a></li>
                <li><a href="noal.jpg">noah</a></li>
                <li><a href="samantha.jpg">samantha</a></li>
                <li><a href="trish.jpg">trish</a></li>
                <li><a href="Blue.png">Blue</a></li>
                <li><a href="stephen.jpg">Stephen</a></li>
                <li><a href="melissa.jpg">Melissa</a></li>
                <li><a href="Matt.jpg">Matt</a></li>
                <li><a href="mitchandseth.jpg">Mitch and Seth</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#next" class="next">Next&nbsp;&gt;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
$(".jmorph").jmorphGallery();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the target="_blank" attribute on A tags ?

Answer (score 1):

after Jmorph loaded replace href attribute (with javascript) to the one you desire

to make it easier you could add id to the href you want replace

should work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to open in a new tab, then you have to use the target attribute in the  anchor tag

```
<a href="cptmorgan.jpg" target="_blank">captain morgan</a>
```

And use correct paths for the images